# Sudo is broken, missing libgcc_s.so

Tags: raspbian, apt, gcc

**tl;dr** Which version of gcc should I install?

Not sure exactly how it happened. It might have been caused by the last upgrade but `sudo` somehow broken. Any `sudo` command I try to run outputs the same:

```
$ sudo apt
apt: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ sudo vim
vim: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm trying to install libgcc using `dpkg` but I'm not sure which version I should be installing. My `os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

For example, I tried installing `libgcc-10-dev_10.4.0-7+rpi1_armhf.deb`:

```
$ wget http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libgcc-10-dev_10.4.0-7+rpi1_armhf.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libgcc-10-dev_10.4.0-7+rpi1_armhf.deb
(Reading database ... 117733 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libgcc-10-dev_10.4.0-7+rpi1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-10-dev:armhf (10.4.0-7+rpi1) over (10.2.1-6+rpi1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcc-10-dev:armhf:
 libgcc-10-dev:armhf depends on gcc-10-base (= 10.4.0-7+rpi1); however:
  Package gcc-10-base is not installed.
 libgcc-10-dev:armhf depends on libgcc-s1 (>= 10.4.0-7+rpi1); however:
  Package libgcc-s1 is not installed.
 libgcc-10-dev:armhf depends on libgomp1 (>= 10.4.0-7+rpi1); however:
  Version of libgomp1:armhf on system is 8.3.0-6+rpi1.
 libgcc-10-dev:armhf depends on libatomic1 (>= 10.4.0-7+rpi1); however:
  Version of libatomic1:armhf on system is 8.3.0-6+rpi1.
 libgcc-10-dev:armhf depends on libasan6 (>= 10.4.0-7+rpi1); however:
  Package libasan6 is not installed.
 libgcc-10-dev:armhf depends on libubsan1 (>= 10.4.0-7+rpi1); however:
  Version of libubsan1:armhf on system is 8.3.0-6+rpi1.

dpkg: error processing package libgcc-10-dev:armhf (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcc-10-dev:armhf
```

**Update**

Installing `libgcc-8-dev_8.3.0-6+rpi1_armhf.deb` was successful but it didn't fix the issue.

Installing `libgcc1_8.3.0-6+rpi1_armhf.deb` fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Installing libgcc1_8.3.0-6+rpi1_armhf.deb fixed the issue!